# Displaying message by calling function from class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

[Stringlength(ErrorMessage= "Get value")] how I want to use this line as generic. i.e. I want it to receive the text of a message that I have in a class.

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(maximumLength:19, ErrorMessage = Helpers.Helpers.DisplayMessage(maxLength: 19, message: "display message") )]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
```

eg: helpers.cs
When I call the DisplayMEssage function, I want it to return the value I set, but I could not. How can I achieve this?

```
public class Helpers
{
    public static string DisplayMessage(string maxLength )
    {
        set
        {
            return "test";
        }
        get
        {
            return "Sonucccc";
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(maximumLength:50, ErrorMessage = Helpers.Helpers.MessageDisplay(message: "Up to {50} characters can be entered.") )]
    public long Username { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(maximumLength:50, ErrorMessage = Helpers.Helpers.MessageDisplay(message: "Up to {50} characters can be entered.") )]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(maximumLength:25, ErrorMessage = Helpers.Helpers.MessageDisplay(message: "Up to {25} characters can be entered.") )]
    public string Business { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can not assign dynamic values to the properties of attribute. Also method declaration in Helpers class is not correct.

Comment: Well. how can I do that.

Comment: It is necessary to send data dynamically and return a value.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. Can you explain the exact requirements? That might help suggesting alternative solution.

Comment: as seen above. error message fixed. only the number changes. I want to do it depending on the variable instead of constantly showing the same error message. I want to write a function and use it everywhere and just send a value.

Comment: You need to change whatever is **using** the attribute, not the attribute itself. Beyond that it's hard to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this can help

You can create your custom attribute and set the `ErrorMessage` the way you like

```
public class CustomStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public CustomStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength): base(maximumLength)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "your error";
    }
}
```

also can have parameters in cunstructor:

```
public class CustomStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public CustomStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength, string msg): base(maximumLength)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = msg;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
[CustomStringLengthAttribute(50, "Up to {50} characters can be entered.")]     
public string Email { get; set; }
```